# [IfcOpneShell]Unabled to add instance from IFC2X3 schema to file with IFC4 schema

Tags: python, ifc-open-shell

I am using IfcOpenShell in python.
When I try to createed a new file and added entity, I get the following error.
How can I get rid of the error?
[program]

```
ifc_file = ifcopenshell.file()
ifc_file.add({IfcBuildingElementProxy})
```

[error]

```
Unabled to add instance from IFC2X3 schema to file with IFC4 schema
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer.
I had to set 'schema'

```
ifc_file = ifcopenshell.file(schema=other_ifc_file.schema)
ifc_file.add({IfcBuildingElementProxy})
```